# Read encoded data in ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

My ajax retrieves the following response in the console:

**PHP**

```
$checkout_session_data = json_encode(['id' => $checkout_session->id]);
wp_send_json_success( $checkout_session_data );

// this is then retuend to the JS ajax function.
```

```
data: "{\"id\":\"cs_test_a1SOgBGIPsRrECu5pP8TDCW16JYMMHnGnmfh7Lp6qf8bvwTk3hK97sI7e7\"}"
success: true
```

I'm unclear how to get the ID value from the response from within the `.done` part of my ajax function.

```
.done( function(response) {
  if( response.success == true ) {
    console.log(response);
  }
```

Attempts:
`console.log(response.data.id);`
`console.log(response[0].id);`

Comment: Did you parse your json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is double encoded, `wp_send_json_success` encodes the data passed to it to JSON so do not `json_encode` your data before you pass it to `wp_send_json_success`,

```
$checkout_session_data = ['id' => $checkout_session->id];
wp_send_json_success( $checkout_session_data );
```

```
.done( function(response) {
  if( response.success == true ) {
    console.log(response.data.id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the ajax request, you would be better served by using the getJSON function here. A sample of the code is shown below.

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });
 
});
```

You can find further details from this link https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON/

Comment: I'd like to stick with ajax for now. Using this for WordPress too.

Comment: In that case, use the following setup.
```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
$.each(data, function(key,val){
//Whatever you want to do with the key.
});
});
```